# How to get right result of this ocaml code?

Tags: ocaml

code:

```
let a = ref 0

type t = 
  | Int of string
  | Add of t * t

let rec makestring_t = function
  | Int a -> a
  | Add (b, c) ->
    incr a;
    "(Add" ^ string_of_int !a ^ 
    " (" ^ makestring_t b ^ 
    " " ^ makestring_t c ^ "))"

let () = 
  let a = Add (Int "1", Add (Int "2", Int "3")) in 
  print_string (makestring_t a)
```

got:

```
(Add2 (1 (Add2 (2 3))))
```

but I want to get answer:

```
(Add1 (1 (Add2 (2 3))))
```

so how to get the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glennsl is quite correct in pointing out that the issue arises from evaluation order. No evaluation order is promised by OCaml. Currently, the evaluation order is not left to right but rather right to left. This is easily demonstrated.

```
# let f a b = () in
  f (print_endline "a") (print_endline "b");;
b
a
- : unit = ()
```

But in the past, a left to right order has been used. *Do not count on either.*

Function calls with side-effects should be explicitly ordered. If possible, avoiding mutable state at all sidesteps this issue entirely.

One other thing you can do to help yourself when converting data types to strings is to leverage the [`Format`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Format.html) module, wrapping your code up in a module keeps things a bit tidier. E.g.

```
module X = struct
  let a = ref 0

  type t =
    | Int of string
    | Add of t * t

  let rec pp ppf =
    function
    | Int a -> Format.fprintf ppf "%s" a
    | Add (b, c) ->
      incr a; 
      let n = !a in
      let open Format in
      let sa = asprintf "%a" pp b in
      let sb = asprintf "%a" pp c in
      fprintf ppf "(Add%d (%s %s))" n sa sb

  let to_string =
    Format.asprintf "%a" pp
end
```

Now:

```
# let () =
    let a = X.(Add (Int "1", Add (Int "2", Int "3"))) in
    Format.printf "%a\n" X.pp a;;
(Add1 (1 (Add2 (2 3))))
# let () =
    let a = X.(
      Add (
        Add (Int "1", Int "5"), 
        Add (Int "2", Int "3")
      )
    ) in
    Format.printf "%a\n" (X.pp) a;;
(Add1 ((Add2 (1 5)) (Add3 (2 3))))
```

Achieving this without mutable state is not quite as simple as Marijn has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76991917/15261315), as that would produce `"(Add1 ((Add2 (1 5)) (Add2 (2 3))))"`. In order to achieve this, a function call has to take an `n` argument *and* return the updated value. Remember, that without mutable state you only have the arguments to a function and its return value to pass along updated information.

```
module X = struct
  type t =
  | Int of string
  | Add of t * t

  let rec to_string_unmut n = 
    function  
    | Int a -> (a, n)
    | Add (b, c) -> 
      let (sb, nb) = to_string_unmut (n + 1) b in
      let (sc, nc) = to_string_unmut nb c in
      (Format.asprintf "(Add%d (%s %s))" n sb sc, nc)
end
```

But, that function doesn't exactly return a string. We can use a locally scoped function to solve this.

```
module X = struct
  type t =
  | Int of string
  | Add of t * t

  let to_string x =
    let rec to_string_unmut n = 
      function  
      | Int a -> (a, n)
      | Add (b, c) -> 
        let (sb, nb) = to_string_unmut (n + 1) b in
        let (sc, nc) = to_string_unmut nb c in
        (Format.asprintf "(Add%d (%s %s))" n sb sc, nc)
    in
    fst @@ to_string_unmut 1 x
end
```

Comment: Thanks!but If avoiding mutable state,how to got "Add1","Add2"...another way to speak:how to do this if I use haskell&happy to got the same result?maybe I have to create a new queastion

Comment: @Chris my answer indeed doesn't count all function calls separately but instead it counts the recursion level - as I mentioned in the answer, that is also why I included a second example that shows two instances of Add2. This may not be what the OP wanted, but it was not specified in the question what the numbering should be in such cases, and future visitors might be interested in the recursion level instead of the number of function calls.

Answer (score 4):

You're incorrectly assuming the order of evaluation of an expression to be left to right. To guarantee a specific order of evaluation, use either the sequence operator, `;`, or `let ... in`.

```
let rec makestring_t = function
| Int a -> a
| Add (b, c) ->
  incr a;
  let n = !a in
  "(Add" ^ string_of_int n ^ " (" ^ makestring_t b ^" "^makestring_t c ^ "))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also explicitly provide the counter variable as a function argument (for example in a tuple), then it will print the level of recursion which may be of interest. In this case you should provide the base level in the first call, but you can use a wrapper expression to start at 1.

```
type t = 
| Int of string
| Add of t * t

let rec makestringn_t =function
|(Int a, _)->a
|(Add (b,c), n)->
 "(Add"^string_of_int(n)^" ("^makestringn_t((b, n+1))^" "^makestringn_t((c, n+1))^"))"

let makestring_t a = makestringn_t (a, 1)

let ()=let a=Add(Int("1"),Add(Int("2"),Int("3"))) in 
 print_endline(makestring_t a)

let ()=let a=Add(Add(Int("1"), Int("2")), Add(Int("3"),Int("4"))) in 
 print_endline(makestring_t a)
```

Result:

```
(Add1 (1 (Add2 (2 3))))
(Add1 ((Add2 (1 2)) (Add2 (3 4))))

type t = Int of string | Add of t * t
val makestringn_t : t * int -> string = <fun>
val makestring_t : t -> string = <fun>
```